# Erro ao conectar MongoDB

Tags: banco-de-dados, node.js, mongodb, express.js

Estou com problemas para conectar o MongoDB.

Segue o código:

```
var express= require('express');

var app= express();

var bodyParser= require('body-parser');

var db_string= 'mongodb://localhost/teste'
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
var db= mongoose.connection;
mongoose.connect(db_string);
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Erro ao conectar no banco'));
db.once('open', function(){
    var testeSchema= mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,

    });
});
```

Erro exibido no console:

```
Erro ao conectar no banco { [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por norma esse erro pode ter várias causas, nomeadamente:

- a porta não é a default(27017)
- o servidor mongo pode estar protegido e o utilizador tem de ser autenticado
- o servidor não está a correr
- a BD não existe

Já agora, falta o `;` na linha `var db_string= 'mongodb://localhost/teste'` (não é obrigatório, mas sempre fica o código mais "arrumado")

Comment: Pode me mostrar melhorias pra arrumar o problema com essas soluções?

Comment: Tentei testar rodar um comando simples pelo terminal: show dbs e obtive o seguinte retorno: Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed

Comment: Executaste o comando do servidor (mongod) 1º?

Comment: Estava com problema na instalação do MongoDb, reinstalei o mesmo e o problema foi resolvido.